Cómo puedo agregar opciones al menú popup del sistema operativo Android

Cuando instalo el navegador vía este se agrega al menú que aparece en WhatsApp y en otras aplicaciones. es una opción general del sistema operativo en el cual se puede agregar opciones al menú popup, me gustaría saber bajo qué api o código lo puedo hacer y como se recibe información de la aplicación donde se uso el menú y como se envia información a esta
